# Selecting rows based on row ánd column values using dplyr in R

Tags: r, select, dplyr, pivot, filtering

When I get data from the very old software I use it looks as follows:S

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

data <- structure(list(`1` = c("agatston", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0"), ...3 = c("area", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0"), ...4 = c("volume", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0"), ...5 = c("density", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0"), ...6 = c("mass", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0"), `10` = c("agatston", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...8 = c("area", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...9 = c("volume", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...10 = c("density", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...11 = c("mass", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), `11` = c("agatston", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...13 = c("area", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...14 = c("volume", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...15 = c("density", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...16 = c("mass", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Which corresponds to the following tibble:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 15
   `1`      ...3  ...4   ...5    ...6  `10`     ...8  ...9   ...10   ...11 `11`     ...13 ...14  ...15   ...16
   <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>
 1 agatston area  volume density mass  agatston area  volume density mass  agatston area  volume density mass 
 2 0        0     0      0       0     0        0     0      0       0     0        0     0      0       0    
 3 0        0     0      0       0     0        0     0      0       0     0        0     0      0       0    
 4 0        0     0      0       0     0        0     0      0       0     0        0     0      0       0    
 5 0        0     0      0       0     0        0     0      0       0     0        0     0      0       0    
 6 0        0     0      0       0     0        0     0      0       0     0        0     0      0       0    
 7 0        0     0      0       0     0        0     0      0       0     0        0     0      0       0    
 8 0        0     0      0       0     0        0     0      0       0     0        0     0      0       0    
 9 0        0     0      0       0     0        0     0      0       0     0        0     0      0       0    
10 0        0     0      0       0     0        0     0      0       0     0        0     0      0       0
```

The columns after `1` that start with '...'. are scores of artery 1, the four columns after `10` are scores of artery 11, and the four columns after column `11` that start with '...' are assessments of artery 11. Every artery has 5 assessments (agatson, area, volume, density, and mass; second row).

The columns that I need are based on 2 conditions:

1. I only need columns labeled 'mass' in the second row.
2. Then, I only need the mass columns of certain arteries.

For example, I am only interested in the mass of arteries 1 and 11, meaning I need the fifth column ('...6') and the fifteenth ('...16'). The two-step process would entail something like scanning the first row for an occurrence of '1' or '11', and then selecting the first following occurrence of 'mass' in the second row. In the current example the preferred output looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   ...11 ...16
   <chr> <chr>
 1 mass  mass 
 2 0     0    
 3 0     0    
 4 0     0    
 5 0     0    
 6 0     0    
 7 0     0    
 8 0     0    
 9 0     0    
10 0     0
```

I have tried formatting to a longer format with `pivot_wider`, or filtering with `dplyr`'s select and filter, but to no avail. If possible, I would like to achieve this using `dplyr`, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you edit your post to include expected output for this data?

Comment: I have updated my question so that perhaps it makes more sense as to what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure on the format you want at the end but I think this is how I would tackle it.

The `janitor` package is super handy and worth looking at more of the functions in there.

```
library(janitor)

data %>%
  row_to_names(row_number = 1) %>% #make first row the title
  clean_names() %>% #make this unique
  select(starts_with("mass")) #select columns that start with mass
```

Comment: Hi Quixotic, thanks for your reply. The thing is, I don't need every variable that mentions 'mass'. What I need is the first mention of mass after, in the row above there is a 10 or a 15 (but not a 11). Would you know of any way to get this?

Answer (score 0):

To select the `'mass'` columns you can do -

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% select(where(~.[1] == 'mass'))

#  ...6  ...11 ...16
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 mass  mass  mass 
# 2 0     0     0    
# 3 0     0     0    
# 4 0     0     0    
# 5 0     0     0    
# 6 0     0     0    
# 7 0     0     0    
# 8 0     0     0    
# 9 0     0     0    
#10 0     0     0
```

I am not clear how you want to select the columns further but adding  `%>% select(2:3)` to the above answer would give you columns `...11` and `...16`.